# DB error when trying to update Stash to 2.5.7

Tags: stash

This is on an EE2.5.5 install. After uploading Stash 2.5.7 and running module updates I get the following DB error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '_last_activity-1-1-435704d2c60667f0c19a4f01903c2b85cd745d51' for key 'cache_key'

ALTER TABLE `exp_stash` DROP INDEX `key_session`, DROP INDEX `key_name`, ADD UNIQUE `cache_key` (`key_name`, `bundle_id`, `site_id`, `session_id`), ADD INDEX `expire` (`expire`)

Filename: third_party/stash/upd.stash.php

Line Number: 186
```

Any ideas? The rest of the install and the site appear unaffected by this.

Comment: Simple question, have you tried uninstalling stash and reinstalling? That's solved the occasional stash upgrade issue with me.

Comment: seems to have done the trick - post this as an answer and I'll aprrove. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above, try uninstalling stash and reinstalling.

Glad I can help.